# jQuery plugin - highlight text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I'm creating a jQuery plugin. It takes user input and should highlight the text in the existing page content. Right now, the plugin is highlighting the entire line which includes the content entered by the user.

Ideally it only matches the entered phrase.

I have three files:

HTML FILE :

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<p>harry gambhir is sitting in oakville tim hortons drinking coffe </p>
```

PLUGIN FILE :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
(function ( $ ) {
$.fn.high = function(){
    $("#name").keyup(function(){
        var user = $(this).val();
        var hhh = $("p:contains('"+ user + "')").addClass('highlight');

    });
};
}(jQuery));
$('p').high();
});
```

CSS FILE:

```
.highlight{

    background-color:#000000;

}
```

Maybe I need to create a span tag around the alphabet then add the class to highlight it. I do not know how to assign a span tag to the entered text. This is just an idea if there is a better solution then please let me know.

Comment: This is really a common thing and there are already a few components out there, e.g. [mark.js](https://markjs.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.html()` , `.text()` , `String.prototype.replace()` , saving original `html` of `p` element as variable to reset `p` element `html` if `.val()` returns empty string

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function($) {
    // pass element selector to `.high()` 
    $.fn.high = function(elem) {
      // cache `this` element
      el = this;
      // save original `html` of `el`
      originalHTML = el.html();
      $(elem).keyup(function() {
        var user = $(this).val();
        // if `user` is not empty string
        if (user.length) {
          el.html(function(_, html) {
            return el.text()
                  .replace(new RegExp("(" 
                    + user.trim().split("").join("|") 
                    + ")"
                  , "g")
                   // replace matched character with `span` element
                   // add `highlight` `class` to `span` element
                   , "<span class=highlight>$1</span>")
          })
        } else {
          // reset `p` : `el` `html` to `originalHTML`
          el.html(originalHTML)
        }

      });
    };
  }(jQuery));
  $("p").high("#name"); // pass `#name` as selector to `.high()`
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" id="name">
<p>harry gambhir is sitting in oakville tim hortons drinking coffe</p>
```

Comment: This will destroy DOM events, as it uses `innerHTML` in the background.